# Maximum edge-weighted subtree T' constrained by number of max k edges, starting with the same root as T

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree

I got an edge-weighted undirected acyclic graph and I have to find a max subtree containing the same root with limited number of edges. I know that it's easy to find a max path and it can be done with dfs, but this problem is very similar to [K-minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-minimum_spanning_tree), which is NP-hard and I couldn't find any implementation suitable for it. I'm looking for a simple, approximate solution to solve this problem.

Comment: Your input graph is undirected and acyclic (and apparently rooted) -- so in other words, it's a tree?

Comment: There's a pretty simple DP if the maximum degree is not too large: At each vertex, calculate the max edge-weighted subtree that uses exactly i edges, for each 0 <= i <= k.  Assume for simplicity a binary tree: Then at the root you just need to "distribute" the k edges between its children in all possible ways: i.e., try giving 0 edges to the left subtree and k to the right, then try giving 1 edge to the left subtree and k-1 to the right, etc.

Comment: yes, its a tree, but not binary, thanks for suggestion, I will try this brute force and check if it doesn't exceed time limit

Comment: If this is for a competition, please post the link so that we know it's not still ongoing.